# WAMPSERVER 403 Forbidden Apache 2.4.18

Tags: apache, wamp

need help I am using apache 2.4.18 wampserver 3.0, I already put it online but I cant access the server remotely from other client. I already configure the `httpd.conf` on `apache\apache2.4.18\conf`, I also search here and did all already from the comments but nothing happens.

below is my configuration:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride All 
    Require all granted  
</Directory>

<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All

#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Your Virtual Host definitions are wrong see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618

Comment: And this change `<Directory />
    AllowOverride All 
    Require all granted  
</Directory>` allows a hacker to see your whole C: drive

Answer (score 0):

If you are working behind firewall OR router make sure port is forwarded to port 80 to access WAMP remotely.

You don't need to change code to do that Just right click on wampserver you will find Put Online Link click over and it's online.

Comment: the firewall is already turned off and port 80 is already in used for IIS.

Comment: so you are using IIS and Apache both at the same time. To make it work change HTTP server port to 8080 or anything via httpd.config (wamp) file and forward port to new port

Comment: hehehe. but the port 8080 is already in use also by Joget(Apache Tomcat). so I use port 8008 for my WAMPSERVER.

Comment: make sure you forwarded the 8008 port via your router or firewall to access it globally.  If you not using any router or firewall then might be windows firewall blocking it to release try this one http://wiki.mcneel.com/zoo/window7firewall

Comment: what did you see you type IP in browser?

Comment: ahhhhh. its 403: forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.